# How to make parent div match height of foreground div without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an animated background that I would like to display behind some text without having to resort to javascript. The text may overflow beyond the viewport. I want the background div to always be the same height as the div containing the text, and I want to achieve this without having to resort to Javascript. Is this possible?

Here is a code sandbox demonstrating my failed attempt:

https://codesandbox.io/s/div-over-div-height-matching-with-only-css-phvejg

And here is the HTML/css snippet in question:

```
<div className="w-screen h-screen">
  <LongBackgroundAnimation />
  <div className="absolute top-0 z-10 m-8 backdrop-blur">
    <p className="">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
      aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
      reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
      pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
      culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code sandbox link is broken. For reference, this is exactly why it's strongly advised that you use the snippet editor in the question itself to create a working example. That being said, it sounds like some CSS is all you need: `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain` depending on your exact use case.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please try the codesandbox link again. I changed its permissions.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the nature of the Rive animation is that it will not display unless a height is assigned to its containing div.

Comment: You can [play](https://codesandbox.io/s/div-over-div-height-matching-with-only-css-forked-tbwmbx?file=/src/App.js) with CSS Grid properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put it in a `grid` and with both grid items in column 1 and row 1, so they are stacked on top of each other.

```
    <div className="w-screen h-screen grid">
      <div className="row-start-1 col-start-1">
        <LongBackgroundAnimation />
      </div>
      <div className="row-start-1 col-start-1 z-10 m-8 backdrop-blur">
        <p className="">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is the most useful answer for me, since it adhered to the same conventions as the original code snippet (TailwindCSS etc). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a somewhat incorrect approach. If the canvas should be used as a background, then it should be specified as an `position: absolute`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#root {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(orange, green);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The original code snippet uses TailwindCSS, and the question is tagged as such. An answer that adheres closely to the conventions adopted by the existing code base would be more useful. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I answered based on the title of the question "using only CSS".

Comment: TailwindCSS is just a set of conventions for CSS, so technically it is still plain CSS.

Comment: Man, I get your point. People on stackoverflow provide answers on a volunteer basis, so it would be nice to ask questions with specific requirements. For example, in your question, I don't see the clarification that you want to get an answer exclusively for `tailwind-css`. By the way, you chose the `javascript` tag, and in the question you ask not to use `javascript`, which is already misleading. Best regards.

Comment: I checked javascript because if you look at the linked code sandbox, you'll see it's running a React app. I think it's helpful to include tags for the entire context in which the code base is running, even if the particular problem to be solved doesn't require it. Thanks again for your help.